# Why is the line integral not coming the same using different parameters

Tags: definite-integrals

I need to calculate the line integral of  (x^2 - x*y)dy when the curve is y=x^2 from (-1,1) to (2,4)
If I convert the x's into y ie x^2=y and x=(y)^1/2 and use the limits 1 to 4 I get -4.9

If I use x as  a parameter and convert the y into x and replace dy by 2xdx and use limits -1 to 2 I do not get -4.9

Why is this so ?

Comment: You cannot parametrize the curve $\;x=\sqrt y\;$ as then the point $\;(-1,1)\;$ is unreachable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=t\;,\;\;y=t^2\;,\;\;-1\le t\le 2\implies \int_C (x^2-xy)dy=\int_{-1}^2(t^2-t^3)2tdt=$$

$$=2\int_{-1}^2(t^3-t^4)dt=\left[\frac12t^4-\frac25t^5\right]_{-1}^2=\frac12(16-1)-\frac25(32-(-1))=$$

$$=\frac{15}2-\frac{66}5=\frac{75-132}{10}=-\frac{57}{10}$$

I don't get $\;-4.9\;$ , either.

Comment: What's wrong with x= (y)^(1/2) parameterization. y=x^2 is equal to x=(y)^(1/3)

Comment: Sorry it's  y=x^2 is equal to x=(y)^(1/2)

Comment: @user379001 No, of course not. The equation $\;y=x^2\;$ defines a straight- upwards parabola and it is defined *for any* $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$, whereas $\;x=y^{1/2}\;$ defines just half a *horizontal-rightwards* parabola (the upper half) and then  it always $\;x\ge0\;$ .

Comment: So if I evaluate the Integral with x=y^(1/2) and limits 0 to 4 and sum it to the Integral with x=-y^(1/2) and limits 1 to 0 , then that's correct. The answer it gives is -5.7.  Is this correct?